# Plugin that does Animation Storage

Tags: animation, blend-files

You know how UE4 does a few things right? Year rare but it does. Here is the question. Is there a plugin that allows you to do what you can do with UE4 with animations? I.E import basically an armature, then import FBXs with the same ones, then use the animation across the board. Of course also storing the animation. Much like you would the pose library over there in its own little list.
It would be far easier to store animations, then export them one by one instead of opening blender project, creating animation, exporting animation, then resetting everything, saving it as a 2nd version, remaking animations, exporting etc. We all know why I would save it as a new blend file. I had to go back to an old rig today and I am so happy I saved it.

Comment: I would recommend removing all references to UE4 to keep the question on point, but aside from that this is a good question. I would look into the NLA editor and retargeting, and if that fails I might just create the addon myself.

Comment: You can also just set the new armature objects to actually use the animated armatures data block, and then duplicate that data block.